# Unable to open the Firefox browser using cmd prompt in watir

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

My system configurations Windows 7, IE8
when I try to open the firefox browser I got the following error can anyone help me how to resolve these.

```
C:\Users\khan>irb

irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true

irb(main):002:0> require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true

irb(main):003:0> e=Watir::Browser.new :firefox
NoMethodError: undefined method `ascii_only?' for {}:Hash
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json_pure-1.4.3/lib/json/pure/generator.rb:393:in `to_json'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/multi_json-1.3.7/lib/multi_json/adapters/json_common.rb:11:in `dump'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/multi_json-1.3.7/lib/multi_json.rb:115:in `dump'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/json_helper.rb:23:in `json_dump'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/profile.rb:254:in `write_prefs'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/profile.rb:253:in `each'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/profile.rb:253:in `write_prefs'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/profile.rb:252:in `open'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/profile.rb:252:in `write_prefs'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/profile.rb:232:in `update_user_prefs_in'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/profile.rb:79:in `layout_on_disk'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:58:in `create_profile'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:34:in `launch'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/socket_lock.rb:20:in `locked'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:32:in `launch'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:20:in `initialize'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `new'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `for'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from (irb):3:in `new'
    from (irb):3
    from ♥:0irb(main):004:0>
```

Comment: hi friends when i try to open the browser in firefox after requiring watir-webdriver i am running into following error

Comment: Is the problem firefox specific or do you get the same exception in other browsers (eg chrome and ie)?

Comment: yaa the issue is with others browsers too....chrome ,its fine with IE

Comment: irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> e=Watir::Browser.new :chrome
Started ChromeDriver
port=9515
version=26.0.1383.0
log=C:\Users\fshaik\chromedriver.log
[5936:4768:1011/151905:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(102)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x4d727d4 closed=false>
irb(main):004:0> [5936:4768:1011/151910:ERROR:textfield.h(176)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
                                            
                     These is the error i got

Answer (score 3):

Based on the exception, you are using an older version of selenium-webdriver and watir-webdriver. It is possible that there is an incompatibility between your selenium-webdriver gem and your Firefox version.

Therefore, I would suggest upgrading your gems:

```
gem install selenium-webdriver
gem install watir-webdriver
```

It might also be possible that one of the dependencies is also incompatible (eg json-pure where the exception occurs). You might want to trying updating everything.

```
gem update
```

Comment: yeah its not working where as in chrome i am able to open the browser but when i say like  "e.goto 'www.gmail.com'" it doesn't navigate to it whereas for firefox it's not working at all

Answer (score 1):

You should try to update gem,I am not sure about it,but try once.

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: yeah when i say gem update--system i got the following error        C:\Users\shaik>gem update --system
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    Could not find a valid gem 'rubygems-update' (2.1.5) locally or in a repository

Comment: its not working  even for gem update--system  any other answer that could resolve it